# Combine two resources and then send to a node in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am simulating a warehouse inspection model where an inspection-officer (present as node1) needs to go to a different node (node2) to collect tools and then go to node where object to be inspected is laid out.

I am using a resource pool for both inspection-officer as well as tools.

Using the following blocks:

source -> seize -> delay -> release -> sink

In the seize block I have configured to use resource-sets (1 inspection-officer and 1 tool)
I have checked the following configs:

- seize units one by one
- Attach seized resources
- Send seized resources

The issue is, both tool and inspection-officer start going to the source separately and then get combined as one unit at the source (and also keep combined while returning to their location), but what I need is the inspection-office should go to the tool, then they should get combined and go to the source node

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the resource start task block. That way one resource will seize the other before being seized by the agent.

Comment: Is it to be used with combination of other blocks?
Can you help me with the flow?
ResourceTaskStart -> (which_block) -> ?

Comment: https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/resourcetaskstart.html

Comment: This link should help

Comment: This definitely helped me look at the right direction, so I am accepting this answer, but for the sake of future users I am answering the block diagram that I followed

Answer (score 1):

resourceTaskStart(to start inspection-officer) -> Seize (to seize the tool) -> moveTo (move to tool node location) -> ResourceAttach(to attach operator and tool) -> moveTo (to send attached unit to source node)

Comment: this will cause problems if this resource can do other things and the tool is not available... the resource will get blocked since it was seized, waiting for a tool to be available without doing nothing, not even moving to the tools location

Comment: I have a competition that aims to solve the generalization of this problem:
https://noorjax.com/2022/04/22/anylogic-contest-2/